# how to get a certain value from a while loop statement

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Could you help me out with my code. 
My code below is a program that fetch all the requests in my database, and every fetched data would have an [Yes/No] aprroval option which is generated by a Radio Button, a button that sends the approval back to my database and a text field for inputting remarks. My problem is, my code only works if I click the first button that is generated. And it won't work whenever I click the proceeding buttons first.

And I can't also get the value of my text field for each records, it seems like it always reads all the empty text fields. 
Please help me out. Thanks. Note: I haven't updated to mysqli yet, and I will do it after I get my problem resolved. Thank you.

```
<html>
<title> Offset Requests </title>

<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="up.css"/> </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Approval()
{
var name;
var rem;
name=document.getElementById('ename').textContent;
rem=document.getElementById('remarks').textContent;
if(document.form1.approval[0].checked==true)
    {   
        alert(name);
        window.location.href = "sqli.php?q=Yes" +"&ecode="+name +"&remarks="+rem;
    }
else if(document.form1.approval[1].checked==true)
    {   
        alert(name);
        window.location.href = "sqli.php?q=No" +"&ecode="+name +"&remarks="+rem;;
    }


}
</script>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$conn)
        echo ("Could not connect");

    mysql_select_db("dbrequests",$conn);

    $query=mysql_query("Select * from offset_form where Approved=''");
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        $ecode=$fetch['Employee_Code'];
        $ename=$fetch['Employee_Name'];
        $epos=$fetch['Employee_Position'];
        $edpt=$fetch['Employee_Department'];
        $dleave=$fetch['Date_Leave'];
        $dreturn=$fetch['Date_Return'];
        $reason=$fetch['Offset_Reason'];

        echo "<div id='ename'> $ecode</div>".$ecode ."".$ename." ".$epos." ".$edpt." ".$dleave." ".$dreturn." ".$reason;
        echo "<input type='radio' name='approval' >Yes";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='approval' >No";
        echo "<input type='text' name='remarks' id='remarks' size='30'>";
        echo"<hr id='br'></hr>";
        echo"<input type='button' value='Submit' name='send' onClick='Approval(this.form)'>";

        }

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code for updating my record:

```
<?php
require 'sqlicon.php';
$q=$_GET['q'];
$ecode= $_GET['ecode'];
$remarks=$_GET['remarks'];
$emp=str_replace(' ', '', $ecode);
var_dump($emp);

echo"".$ecode;
$result=$db->query("UPDATE offset_form SET Approved='".$q."', Manager_Remarks='".$remarks."' WHERE Employee_Code='".$emp."'");
header("Location:testingjava.php");
```

?>

Comment: To make it clearer, I am trying to fetch all employee's leave requests. And I will choose whose request should I approve. So, each record would have a Yes/No approve radio button, a text field that is where I would put my reason or remarks why I disapprove or approve the request, and a button that will send my approval anwsers back to the database. 

So, my problem is, I can only approve the first record that is fetched. If I choose to aprrove any records below that first record, my code won't generate.
But even if I tried to put remarks on the first text field, it still gives an empty data.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, But my code is for fetching all the pending requests from my records, meaning,it should fetch all the requests that I haven't disapprove or approve yet.

Comment: Yes, it puts a Yes or No value in the Approved field depends if I choose the Yes or No radio button. But it can't get the data on my text field.

Comment: So it won't put in your remarks? Sorry for so many questions but I can't help unless I paint a clear picture.

Comment: Yes yes, that's one of my problems. Sorry if my description is really confusing.

Comment: Ok, then we need to see your updating method... post it in the above code where you update something after a button is clicked.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I edited my post.. I put the update method. Please look at it.. thanks.

Comment: Change the 'name' of the No input field to 'unapproved' and then the $q=$_GET['unapproved'] and try that for me... It doesn't seem like $_GET['q'] has anything to actually get...

Comment: umm.. but that q is the one that holds and sends the value yes or no from my records form to my update form.

Comment: I got my text field problem resolved. I change my rem=document.getElementById('remarks').textContent to rem=document.getElementById('remarks').value because textContent doesn't work for getting inputed values on a text field. Thank You for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

As [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) return index key and you are trying associative value . Replace `mysql_fetch_array` with [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)

your loop will be:-

```
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

         .........
}
```

You can debug your query whether its working or not like this:-

```
 $query=mysql_query("Select * from offset_form where Approved=''", $conn);
 echo mysql_errno($conn) . ": " . mysql_error($conn) . "\n"
```

Comment: it still doesn't work.. But thank you for answering.

Comment: Can you please check `Select * from offset_form where Approved=''` this query whether its returning some value or not.